# How to hide and show a text box on a radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want the textbox in the code below to show when the user selects 'Yes' and to hide if they select 'No'.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 130px">
            <label for="edit-title" class="control-label" style="font-size: small;">Willing to Post?</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="yesnopricing" checked="checked">&nbsp;&nbsp;No</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" style="padding-left: 20px;" value="1" name="yesnopricing">&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes</td>

        <td style="width: 25px"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="postageprice" placeholder="Postage Price">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So you've tagged your question with PHP, JavaScript, and jQuery, yet posted no code from any of those languages. What have you tried?

Comment: Although you have a table based layout which doesn't really work with this, there is support to do this in pure CSS using the `:checked` selector if you can refactor the markup: http://jsbin.com/kitekozexe/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Try to do some dom traversing then do a toggle with value,

```
$(":radio[name='yesnopricing']").change(function(){
  $(this).parent().nextAll("td:has(input[name='postageprice'])").toggle(!!+this.value);
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/2rvsb22z/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add event onclick to both inputs of type radio. Then check which one is selected and depends on that call method hide() or show() on input type text.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `class` or `id` to identify your inputs and then use click `event` to show hide your field, check the example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$('body').on('click', '.yes_pricing', function(){
     $('#post_age_price').show();
})

$('body').on('click', '.no_pricing', function(){
     $('#post_age_price').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table >
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 130px">   
      <label for="edit-title"  class="control-label" style="font-size: small;">Willing to Post?</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class='no_pricing' type="radio" value="0" name="yesnopricing">&nbsp;&nbsp;No</td>
    <td><input class='yes_pricing'type="radio" style="padding-left: 20px;" value="1" name="yesnopricing" checked="checked">&nbsp;&nbsp;Yes</td>

    <td style="width: 25px"></td>
    <td>    <input id="post_age_price" type="text"  name="postageprice" placeholder="Postage Price"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your comment on this. How do I add the snippet into the page?

Comment: You're welcome, check **[Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)**.